# Enzyme/Jest: How to test if mocked function has been called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test for the call of `fetch()` inside of my `changeIt()` function using jest/enzyme.
But obviously I'm doing something wrong:

**example.js**

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

export default class Example extends Component {
  changeIt (id, value) {
    fetch('http://localhost/set-status?id=' + id + '&value=' + value)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>something </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**example.test.js**

```
jest.mock('node-fetch')
test('should call fetch()', () => {
  const id = 1
  const value = 50
  const fetch = jest.fn() // <- This is wrong
  const wrapper = shallow(<Example />)
  wrapper.instance().changeIt(id, value)
  expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalled() // <- This is wrong
})
```

Comment: have you mocked 'node-fetch'?

Comment: @axm__ yes, like shown in the test code

Comment: But then you create a new local mock function, unrelated to node-fetch, inside the test function. Look again at https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html#mocking-modules

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to properly mock the `node-fetch` module. Because it is in `node_modules`, you need to put `node-fetch` inside a `__mocks__` folder on the same level as `node_modules` like:

```
├── node_modules/
│   ├── node-fetch/
├── __mocks__/
│   ├── node-fetch.js
```

Inside `node-fetch.js` put:

```js
export default jest.fn();
```

Finally import `fetch` in your test file and mock it like this:

```
import Example from './Bla';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
/**
 * Important! Import the mocked function.
 * Start the mocking with jest.mock('node-fetch').
 * Stop the mocking with jest.unmock('node-fetch').
 */    
jest.mock('node-fetch');

test('should call fetch()', () => {
  const id = 1
  const value = 50
  const wrapper = shallow(<Example />)
  wrapper.instance().changeIt(id, value)
  expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalled() // now it works
})
```

[Read more about mocking `node_modules` packages in jest here.](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks)

Comment: Understand and it is working. Then I don't need `jest.mock('node-fetch')`

Comment: That was a bit unclear of me, I will edit that. you STILL need to do that because per test you can mock / unmock.